# Angular2 and jQuery plugins working together perfectly?

Tags: jquery, typescript, angular

When trying to integrate jQuery plugins with Angular 2, we have three scenarios:

1.ONLOAD : initiate plugin on page load, which works great with code below:

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    ...
    $('#somedatatable1').DataTable()
    ...
}
```

---

2.ONCLICK : initiate plugin on click, by retrieving server generated html (I know html should not be transferred in json, but just data, but this is what I have) and feeding it to the page, and then initiate DataTable plugin on that data:

maincomponent.ts

```
clickDatatableParse(){
    this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
        .map(res => res.json()) 
        .subscribe(
            data => { 
                this.data = data
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("fetched!")
        )
}
```

maincomponent.html

```
<div id="contents" [innerHTML]="data?.htmltable">
```

PARSED Html output after data is retrieved and parsed

```
<div id="contents">
    <div id="somedatatable2">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

**Question is** where to put "$('.somedatatable2').datatables();" so it will work properly. So, everything needs to be retrieved and parsed fully, and then call jQuery plugin on it, then it will work.

---

3.ONCLICK SUBCOMPONENT is when I click, the subcomponent is being activated

maincomponent.ts

```
clickDatatableParse(){
    this.http.get(this.jsonUrl)
        .map(res => res.json()) 
        .subscribe(
            data => { 
                this.data = data
            },
            err => console.log(err),
            () => console.log("fetched!")
        )
}
```

maincomponent.html

```
<div id="subcomponent" [htmldata]="data?.htmltable">
```

subcomponent.html

```
<div id="subcomponentbody" [innerHTML]="htmldata">
    ....
</div>
```

PARSED Html output after data is retrieved and parsed

```
<div id="subcomponentbody">
    <div id="somedatatable3">
        ....
    </div>
</div>
```

subcomponent.ts

```
ngAfterViewChecked(){
    ...
    $('#somedatatable3').DataTable()
    ...
}
```

**Question is** if this is something that should work? I assume that initiating plugin in subcomponent via ngAfterViewChecked better choice or not?

---

**Question is** how properly to include jQuery plugin. I think that I should import the plugin via "import * as Datatables from 'jquery-datatables'" and "npm install jquery-datatables --save" before that, and then just put in .css file of the plugin into the @component styleUrls: ['datatables.css','main.css']. Is this proper way to do it?

Comment: They work very well unless jquery tries to do dom manipulation that is handled by angular2, at PrimeNG we use some of the PrimeUI widgets that are jquery based. See the code at github for integration. Make sure you destroy the widget with ngDestroy otherwise widget will be initialized more than once. http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/ Also DataTable is a native Angular2 component in PrimeNG which makes sense for a complex component like that.

Answer (score 0):

I have used `ngAfterViewInit` hook and it works like a charm. A problem may arise when Angular manipulates the DOM. A workaround to that problem would be to refresh the table each time Angular manipulates the DOM by calling `$("#sometable").DataTable()`

Comment: The values never populates in DataTable table. Can you help me on the same.